# How to implement factory pattern when using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to work with my MongoDB documents and have thee models:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Doc', mongoose.Schema({
    type: 'doc'
}, collection: "doc");

module.exports = mongoose.model('Folder', mongoose.Schema({
    type: 'folder'
}, collection: "doc");

module.exports = mongoose.model('Unit', mongoose.Schema({
    type: 'unit'
}, collection: "doc");
```

At some point (on ajax request coming for example) I need to create model at several type:

```
app.post('/doc/create/:type', function (req, res, next) {
    var type = req.params.type;
    var data = req.body;

    // how to create model based on incoming type here?
    // var model = new Factory.create(type); ???
});
```

I need to know best practices to work with similar models and create instance from factory or something else.

Please share your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a model from a string by using something like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var model = mongoose.model('Unit')
```

PS: If this is the solution to your problems, I'm wondering if the way you are designing your database models is actually the proper one! Can't you create a single model "Doc" with an indexed "type" property? It would be more efficient in many ways.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't create single model because each other has different fields.

Comment: You could just define all the possible fields and then not use them (fields that are 'undefined' are not stored in Mongo by Mongoose)

Comment: I don't want to store all possible fields in single model due to separate logic and data. I'm looking for solution to create factory.